# Update values outside the tableview scope when values inside are updated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a label placed in my viewcontroller and a tableview when the value of label inside of tableview is changed I want to show that value on my label outside of tableview as well
I have stored the value in a var in my cell class and it updates  but the label is not updating, please help.

Button actions in tableview cell

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
    count += 1
    totalAmount = ItemAmount * Double(count)
    totalCharge += ItemAmount
}
@IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if count > 0{
        count -= 1
        totalAmount = ItemAmount * Double(count)
        totalCharge -= ItemAmount
    }
}
```

I have declared totalCharge as public and accessing it in the viewcontroller and giving the value to the label in cellforRowat

Comment: Could you share some code, so people can assist you further? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try to assign value of variable totalCharge to lable as a text. (If variable is in integer find how to assign integer value to UILable?)

Comment: Simply by String(Int Value) @HardikThakkar

Answer (score 0):

You have two different reference objects (your view controller and your cell class), so you will need to use a protocol to communicate between the two objects.  Here is an example:

```
//define the protocol
protocol updateLabelsDelegate {
 func updateLabels(itemAmount: Double)
}

//Add the delegate to your cell class
class customCell: UITableViewCell {

 var delegate: updateLabelsDelegate?

 @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
    count += 1
    totalAmount = itemAmount * Double(count)
    totalCharge += itemAmount
    delegate.updateLabels(itemAmount: itemAmount)
 }
 @IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if count > 0{
        count -= 1
        totalAmount = itemAmount * Double(count)
        totalCharge -= itemAmount
        delegate.updateLabels(itemAmount: itemAmount)
    }
 }
}

//Conform to the protocol in your view controller
extension ViewController: updateLabelsDelegate {
 func updateLabels(itemAmount: itemAmount) {
 //... take the itemAmount value passed here and use it to update your label on the view controller
 }
}
```

One last thing, use proper casing with itemAmount (not ItemAmount, unless it's a static class object, like a singleton).